# Selenium WebDriver -- get <span> text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to get the price value $726.35 from:

```
<span id="paiement-resultats"class="calculateur-resultats-total" style="" xpath="1">$726.35</span>
```

but it doesn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("paiement-resultats")).getText()
```

How can I get this value?

Screenshot from the browser:

[image: Screenshot from the browser]

Comment: You don't need that `@` in this case. Try simply `driver.findElement(By.id("paiement-resultats")).getText()`

Comment: @Andersson I can see that you've got some "russkii klaviatura" judging by your edit :)

Comment: @alecxe , Yeah, sorry, didn't pay attention to selected keyboard layout :))

Comment: As an addition to [Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson)'s reply, I suggest to not use xpath if you have other options. Refer to this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355003/advise-on-hierarchy-for-element-locators-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @kery is it possible to share a link to the webpage? It will be quicker to check it in JS console with jQuery, if that works you can just use selenium's browser.execute_script to execute jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element is within a `<span>` tag, to extract the text **$726.35** you can use either of the following solution:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.calculateur-resultats-total#paiement-resultats")).getText();
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='calculateur-resultats-total' and @id='paiement-resultats']")).getText();
  ```

---

### Update

As the results were unstable you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibilityOfElementLocated* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table[aria-label='User']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[contains(@style,'vertbar')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

Comment: @kery Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Yes, it works )

        String myText = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='calculateur-resultats-total' and @id='paiement-resultats']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

Below i have Mentioned Two Xpath Try With that, if not working Let Me Know

```
//div[@id='resultats']//following::span[@id='paiement-resultats']
//div[@id='resultats']//following::span[@class='calculateur-resultats-total']

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='resultats']//following::span[@id='paiement-resultats']")).getText()
```

Comment: Unfortunately no(( returning empty string in both cases

Comment: Try Now, i have updated the Xpath. Now also not Working Means Let Me Know ! @kery

Answer (score -1):

Cheers!
I found the solution

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='calculateur-resultats-total' and contains(text(),'$')]")).getText();
```

Comment: `contains(text(),'$')` and then `getText()`?